# priority_queue<vector<int> > pq; is saything that "priority_queue" is not a template, how would I fix this?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

priority_queue<vector<int> > pq;
```

Priority_queue is saying that it is not a template

Comment: Try `#include <queue>` at the top of your program. `std::priority_queue` is defined in this header.

Answer (score 2):

No such template was defined in your shown code, anywhere, hence the compiler is complaining, for that precise reason. It's a very straightforward complaint from your C++ compiler.

If you would like to define that template, that's done by an

```
#include <queue>
```